# Why does this function change the order of the array items?

Tags: javascript

The function should return the earliest complete pair that equals the sum (s);

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s, arr = ints.slice(), result) {
  let lastIndex = arr.length;
  for (let int of arr) {
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (int + arr[i] === s && i < lastIndex) {
        result = [int, arr[i]];
        lastIndex = i;
      }

    }
   arr.splice(0, 1); 
  }
  return result;
}

  console.log(sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)); // [3,7] is expected
  // console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 2));
  // console.log(sumPairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2));
  // console.log(sumPairs([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8));
   console.log(sumPairs([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)); // [0,-6] is expected
  // console.log(sumPairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6));
```

For the examples that are returning oddly, I have listed the expected results next to the function call/console log.

Comment: Let's turn this around: _why_ do you say that `sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10));` should yield `[3,7]`? Specifically, looking at `result = [int, arr[i]];`, why would `int` be 3, and `arr[i]` be 7 at the end of your uninterrupted for-loop?

Comment: Or, why not `[5, 5]`, since a 5 comes before both 3 and 7 in the first array example?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained this in my OP. The function should return the earliest complete pair that equals the sum (s);

Comment: Then why are you letting it keep on running after the first result? =) (Also, explain to yourself why you have that `array.splice` there, because that has no business being in this code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splicing inside the loop, you're removing one element from the beginning of the array *while you're iterating over the array*. This results in the `int` variable being iterated over being only *every other* value, eg:

```
sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)
          ^^     ^     ^
```

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s, arr = ints.slice(), result) {
  let lastIndex = arr.length;
  for (let int of arr) {
    console.log(int);
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (int + arr[i] === s && i < lastIndex) {
        result = [int, arr[i]];
        lastIndex = i;
      }

    }
    arr.splice(0, 1);
  }
  return result;
}

sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)
```

So the first item in the returned array is *never* an odd index.

Why splice? It's not doing anything for you at all, and doesn't make sense for the algorithm.

To return the first pair that exists, construct a Set of the numbers needed to be found to sum to the desired amount. For example, when iterating over 3 with a target of 10, add 7 to the Set.

```js
function sumPairs(ints, target) {
  const set = new Set();
  for (const num of ints) {
    if (set.has(num)) return [target - num, num];
    set.add(target - num);
  }
}

console.log(sumPairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)); // [3,7] is expected
console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 2));
console.log(sumPairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2));
console.log(sumPairs([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8));
console.log(sumPairs([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)); // [0,-6] is expected
console.log(sumPairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6));
```

Comment: First time seeing the set object, I'll look over this and try to understand what's going on. Thanks so much!

Comment: You could do the same with an array - the code would look almost exactly the same - it'd just be more computationally complex